# Desktop folder icon is vanished in Nautilus sidebar

Tags: nautilus

My Desktop folder is vanished in the left bar of Nautilus, but I can still open it using the right click in the desktop and selecting "Show the desktop in file" or choosing it from the home folder in Nautilus. I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: please look at the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` to check if the line `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/Something"` exists and is valid

Comment: yes, it exists, but still nothing changed

Comment: why should something change if it exists?.. -- another idea: is your desktop customized with a theme ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bring back my Desktop Icon in Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080582/how-to-bring-back-my-desktop-icon-in-nautilus)

Comment: Also related to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1135565/349837), and maybe to the fact that Files (Nautilus) [v3.28 lose the desktop icons](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/files-nautilus-v3-28-will-lose-the-desktop-icons-capability/3115) capability and [added back on v3.30](https://www.ubuntufree.com/gnome-3-30-brings-back-desktop-icons-with-nautilus-integration-wayland-support/).

Answer (score 2):

Go to Files or Home to open a Nautilus window and click on `Files` on the top bar of the screen alongside Activities.

This will give you a drop down menu from which you can select to invoke the Sidebar (or deactivate it if already selected).

Then with a ✔ alongside the option as required the Sidebar will be reactivated/recycled.

If the `Desktop` folder is still not shown in the sidebar it is probably because the `Local Network Share` has been lost.

It can be restored by opening your `Home` folder, right click on the`Desktop` folder icon and select `Local Network Share` from the drop down options.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/home/YOUR-USERNAME/Desktop` in Nautilus, then press <kbd>Ctrl + B</kbd> to bookmark the location, and you'll have a "Desktop" item in the Nautilus sidebar.

Comment: doing this I add it at the bottom of the sidebar, but I wanted it back where the "important" directories are

Comment: It's no longer there due to a change in recent Nautilus versions.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Gnome Tweaks installed, so launch it.

On the left in Tweaks, select *Desktop*. Make sure *Show Icons* option is checked on the right.

[image: screenshot]